# How to get how many lines you wrote in Github project and how many lines you wrote were deleted

Tags: python, git, github

My senior has given me a task to find out the number of lines I wrote in a GitHub project and how many of those lines were deleted. Are there any built-in methods available to achieve this? Keep in mind that I am not the only developer on the project. My senior wants proof that my code is not up to par.

Comment: If your senior thinks number of lines has any real meaning, maybe you need a new senior.

Comment: And you want to support him with his claims? If he wants to proof that, let him do the proof. You should have the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: BTW I delete most of my written lines of code myself. How does he want to take that into account?

Comment: As a senior: they almost certainly set this task as an exercise, not because they need those numbers. Read up on the github API, and then find the functions that let you get commit or merge request information, because `git` tracks that information as part of the diffs it stores. If they _do_ want it in order to make job performance calls, then the appropriate response is "do it yourself, you can program better than I can and you should already have access to the repo charts".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go on the page of the Github project click, on the top bar, go to the insights and after on the contributors on the left after. After a loading you gonna see the additions (green) and deletions (red) for each person, which is the number of line add and delete by contributors.

Comment: What about the second number?

Comment: @Diamons, this could be a useful recommendation, but it doesn't work in a closed repository.

Comment: This command help to calculate all your lines in project
 $ git ls-files | xargs wc -l | grep -o "[0-9]* total" | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM}' , but I can't find a command to chow your deleted lines.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but may be still there are a solution in only one command.

```
git log --shortstat --since="1 year ago" --until="now" \
  | grep "files changed\|Author\|Merge:" \
  | awk '{ \
    if ($1 == "Author:") {\
      currentUser = $2;\
    }\
    if ($2 == "files") {\
      files[currentUser]+=$1;\
      inserted[currentUser]+=$4;\
      deleted[currentUser]+=$6;\
    }\
  } END {\
    for (i in files) {\
      print i ":", "files changed:", files[i], "lines inserted:", inserted[i], "lines deleted:", deleted[i];\
    }\
  }'
```